# Why I get acidic solution at brine anode?

Tags: electrochemistry, salt

I have decomposed $\ce{NaCl}$ solution (brine) with electrolysis and yield $\ce{NaOH}$ at cathode, at anode I got acidic while expected was $\ce{NaClO}$ (alkaline) if it is $\ce{HOCl + HCl}$. Where does sodium ion goes, and if it doesn't, then why?

[image]

Comment: The sodium ions go where the electric field drives them. How could they not to?

Comment: so the sodium ion goes to sodium hydroxide solution and make hypochlorus acid at the anode

Comment: Well, basically yes, that's about it.

Comment: what if i put the anode and cathode in the same beaker and the same brine solution

Comment: Then the separation will be smaller, and if you stir the solution, it won't develop at all.

Comment: i am feared why acting like bleach(sodium hypochlorite) it stains black cloths